# Bash echo weird behavior

Tags: linux, bash, shell, newline, carriage-return

I wrote a script to change .CSV to json.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 0< example.csv

while IFS=, read name element input decrease
do
   echo "${element}decrease: ${decrease}test"
done
```

the example.csv I paste here

```
name1,A,11,12
name2,B,13,14
```

But the output is really weird...

```
testrease: 12
testrease: 14
```

As u can see, The `test` rewrite `Adecrease` and `Bdecrease`, makes them to `testrease`.

I can't believe it!!  So I tried with out `exec 0< example.csv`, type them in stdin, this time I got what I want

```
name1,A,11,12
Adecrease: 12test
```

So I guess maybe there are some characters in example.csv I can't see which makes this problem.  I use `cat -v example.csv`

```
name1,A,11,12^M
name2,B,13,14^M
```

Nothing strange and I stuck here.

I am very new to shell script, so if anyone can give me some suggestions I will be really thrilled!!

Comment: `  ^M ` doesn't look strange?

Comment: This is the first thing the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) asks you to check for before posting a question.

Comment: Thank u, guys! Seems like i make a stupid mistake.... When i use vim and set invlist it didn't show me the nausea '^M'.

Comment: In vim, you can run `:set fileformat=unix` to cause your file to be written with UNIX newlines next time it's saved. Presumably it was autodetected as `fileformat=dos`, so vim is treating the CRs as normal (for a DOS text file, not a UNIX one), hence them not showing up when you enable display of invisible characters.

Answer (score 0):

Thank u, [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)! [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) saves me another hour on this stupid question.

And here is the solution from wiki:

> #### Check whether your script or data has DOS style end-of-line characters.
>
> - Use `cat -v yourfile` or `echo "$yourvariable" | cat -v`.
>
>   DOS carriage returns will show up as `^M` after each line.
>
>   If you find them, delete them using `dos2unix` (a.k.a. `fromdos`) or `tr -d '\r'`.